# Forms Authentication not working in .html file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using forms authentication in IIS7 to password-protect a dev site, but the authentication seems to get by-passed when the site contains only static HTML files + login.aspx + web.config.

When I renamed the files to .aspx, I am prompted with the login form I am not doing anything fancy. I have a very simple login script and it should just redirect to index.html afterward.

Any suggestions? To summarize, the entire site is using HTML (for now) and needs to be password protected.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="/" loginUrl="/Login.html" timeout="360" slidingExpiration="true">

      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<location>` section to define a directory to protect

```
<configuration>
    <location path="/">
          <system.web>
             <authorization>
                <deny users="?"/>
             </authorization>
          </system.web>
       </location>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: error : 
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: `<location path="/">
  
  <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="/" loginUrl="/Login.html" timeout="360" slidingExpiration="true">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

</location>`

Comment: where you put this section? it should outside system.web

Comment: let me find a standard version for you. not so easy to type on phone

Comment: Ok i am waiting

Comment: i updated the answer, you need put the location section under configuration section

Comment: please see 2nd comment what i write

Comment: don't put any other element, only authorization section